# Problema con placepicker de google api place

Tags: google-maps, fragment, google-play-services

Estoy implementando la api de google places en mi aplicación , estoy trabajando con un bottom navigation como menu , por lo cual tengo distintos fragments que son las opciones , ejemplo inicio , buscar, ajustes, etc. Implemente place picker en uno de los fragments , y al ejecutar y seleccionar ese fragment en la app aparece el mapa y todo , pero se sale vuelve al menú principal, no entiendo porque, ¿alguna idea?. Saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede apreciar en la imagen selecciono la opción de buscar se abre el mapa pero se sale , como se puede ver en la imagen que se esta saliendo

```
package com.example.larra21.myapplication;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class BuscarFragment extends Fragment {

 int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
 public BuscarFragment() {
  // Required empty public constructor
 }


 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buscar, container, false);

  PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
  Intent intent;
  try {
   intent = builder.build(getActivity());
   startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
  } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return v;



 }

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, getActivity());
    String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  }
 }

}
```

Comment: Hola Felipe, tu pregunta no es clara. ¿Podrías agregar un __[mcve]__ para comprender mejor tu problema? Espero que sea posible.

Comment: agregue a la pregunta una imagen

Comment: Revisa tu pregunta y analiza si tu mismo la entiendes... y si puedes, lee también esta guía: _[ask]_.